# Why does gamed, on my local network, request connections to my public IP?

Tags: network, game-center

Like [others](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/264466/220420), I've noticed that gamed is quite chatty.  One thing I've noticed through Little Snitch though that I find a bit strange, is that gamed keeps hitting my externally visible public IP address.  My machine is on a local WiFi network with 192.168.. addresses, but gamed is trying to hit ports on the IP address assigned to my DSL connection.

Any idea why it needs to connect to my network like a stranger?

Comment: I suspect it's testing properties of your firewall/router setup to determine how to advertise yourself to peers on Game Center.